# Unable to receive request in next.js application

Tags: node.js, next.js

I'm using Next.js first time and I have design my first API endpoint in this way as below in image.

[image]

After that, when I hit the API from postman, I'm not receiving API in server.

**http://localhost:3000/user/kyc/upload**

[image]

I'm sure I'm doing some very silly mistake. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have figured it out and I have really made a silly mistake in API endpoint in postman. I didn't put `/api` in URL.

The updated and correct API end point is as below.

`http://localhost:3000/api/user/kyc/upload`

Now it's working fine for me.